# Installing STS encountered an issue. An error ocurred while collecting items to be installed

Tags: java, eclipse

Installation error for STS:
[image: Installation error for STS]

Please help as I m new to eclipse

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGaBp.jpg please find this image as it consists of error

Comment: STS is not eclipse. it's an IDE based on eclipse. since the installation is basically 'unzipping an archive' you can't really go wrong there. showing us an image of a partial error message with a vague description of what triggered it, won't really do any of us (or you, for that matter) any good.
I would recommend you to ask your question, the way their official page recommends it: on SO with the tag of springsource toolsuite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=spring-tool-suite

Comment: STS is SpringToolsSuite. Its basically Spring boot frame work

Comment: Its fine for me if u can't help.

Comment: "it's basically spring boot frame work", no, it isn't. It is a customized IDE based on eclipse, in which (by default) several Spring plugins have been added. I'm merely pointing out that (even if the official pages of SpringTool Suite claim to), StackOverflow isn't really the place to ask questions about "how to install" an IDE. Your explanation of when you get the error is vague, and you only show a partial error message (better yet, a print screen of one), so, yes, I don't think I'll be much help.

Comment: @Stultuske I think the OP's problem is arising from trying to install the [**"Spring Tools"** plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-aka-spring-ide-and-spring-tool-suite) on Eclipse, which is also confusingly known as "Spring Tool Suite" or "STS". So the OP is trying to upgrade Eclipse with a plugin to make it similar to the Eclipse based IDE named STS. The [STS download page](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all) explicitly mentions _"As an alternative, you can also install STS directly from the Eclipse Marketplace"_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install STS on eclipse oxygen 4.7.3a for linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50488963/2985643) See the first comment to the OP for a possible solution.